# best way to handle conditions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this line of code which I feel so bad about it.

```
{paymentType === "CASH" && status !== "ACCEPTED" && <OnOffButton type="cash" on={status === "CREATED"?false:true} />}
{paymentType === "CASH" && status === "ACCEPTED" && <OnOffButton onClick={()=> status === "CREATED" ? setActionBox({type: 'CREATED'}) : setActionBox({type: 'ACCEPTED'})} type="cash" on={status === "CREATED"?false:true} />}
```

as you can see the condition difference between first and second line is the status, and for the first option, I don't want to have a onClick . is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Shorten the code, or something else? What is the possible values for status? What is the implementation for OnOffButton / where do you import it from? Please be more specific and give us a reproducible example.

Comment: As I mentioned when status is not ACCEPTED, I want to remove onClick function, so if user click, nothing happens. I can add a disable to OnOffButton but still click happens. i want to completely remove the click option.

I want to have one line for it and not 2

Comment: You are removing the `onClick` function when status is not ACCEPTED, therefore you don't want to achieve that. You want to achieve a better code. So, what do you want? Please edit your question and clarify, perhaps include OnOffButton implementation if it is your code or the library if it is imported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly better refactor of your logic:

```
import React from 'react'

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const paymentType = 'CARD';
  const status = 'ACCEPTED';

  if (paymentType !== 'CASH') {
    return null;
  }

  const isOn = status === 'CREATED';
  const isAccepted = status === 'ACCEPTED';

  return (
    <OnOffButton
      type="cash"
      on={isOn}
      onClick={() => isAccepted && setActionBox({ type: status })}
    />
  )
}

export default ExampleComponent
```

Comment: I like this but I also wait for more answers. Thank you

Comment: I refactored it even more, see my new edit above.

Comment: yeah, it is much better now. thanks